# Pinging in order to show networkstatus in application (Questions)

Tags: c#, wpf

I got some questions regarding pinging operations in an application.
I implemented a control which shows if the computer has internet access or not and a control which shows the reachability of a mysql server.
Therefore I currently use `TcpClient` to check if a connection to both addresses could be established or not.

Question 1):
Are there any issues with pinging google.com? Atm I ping www.google.com every 2 seconds.
Is it possible that the google servers won't respond because of a spamming presumption? (My application has to run about 72hours and it will ping every 2 seconds for 72 hours)

Question 2):
Do you have any useful tips regarding this topic? Is there anything to care about when implementing such things?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can't you check the access to the server instead of the internet? And if the server is unresponsive, then ping google

Comment: yes this is possible too, in order to route most of the pings to my own server. but the main reason i'm asking this is because I would like to know if there could happen some kind of banning when pinging to often in a short period of time.

Comment: It could, of course. As you have no control over the other server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InternetGetConnectedState

Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384702(v=vs.85).aspx